# Windows Server IIS Configuration For SendGrid SSL Click Tracking

Tags: hyperlink, sendgrid, branding, click-tracking

I would like to be able to use the Link Branding with SSL in SendGrid for Click Tracking.  I followed the instructions for link branding and have it all setup on my DNS Server.  I would prefer to use the custom SSL configuration instead of a CDN like CloudFare because I do not want to change my DNS Server, which CloudFare would like to do when I tried to setup a free account.

Therefore, my preference is to use my Windows Server IIS setup to handle the Custom SSL Configuration.  The instructions that [SendGrid provides from their Support Web site](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/custom-ssl-configurations) is a bit vague.

Can someone provides a more elaborate reference on how to use my IIS Server to manage the Custom SSL Configuration to satisfy SendGrid's Link Branding for Click Tracking?

Comment: Yes, I contacted SendGrid and they sent me an Email on how to get it resolved.